# Magento remove 0 value attribute in Layer Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

How to disable attribute in layer navigation if that attribute have 0 values

i used this

```
<?php if($_item->getCount() > 0):?>
    <li>

        <?php $inputId = $_item->getFilter()->getRequestVar().'_'.$_item->getValue() ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $inputId ?>" name="<?php echo $_item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl(true)) ?>" <?php if ($_item->isSelected()):?>checked="checked"<?php endif ?> />
        <label for="<?php echo $inputId ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?> 
            <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
            <span class="em_count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
            <?php endif ?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <?php endif;?>
```

it disable Values but **Lable** How to disable this Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Catalog -> Attributes -> search the corresponding attribute.

In the `Properties` tab look for `Frontend Properties`. Change the value for `Use In Layered Navigation` from `Filterable (no results)` to `Fileterable (with results)`. This should exclude any filterable attributes that would have zero results.